# Как закешировать jQuery на клиенте?

Tags: jquery, кэширование

Если я для каждой страницы загружаю jQuery и некоторые другие библиотеки,  то можно ли их как-нибудь закешировать на клиенте?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этой цели обычно используется заголовок HTTP `Expires`. Поскольку у библиотеки JQuery при обновлении всегда меняется имя файла - можно вообще ставить "вечное" кеширование (на 100 лет вперед, к примеру).

Еще можно загружать JQuery с CDN, потому что так библиотека будет кешироваться даже между сайтами - но я бы не рекомендовал поступать подобным образом, поскольку CDN могут и выключить, а библиотека весит не настолько много.

**Обновление**

Использовать библиотеку без указания номера версии - как раз не лучшая идея. В зависимости от реализации, для нее может быть либо отключен заголовок `Expires` - либо будут наблюдаться проблемы с кэшем, когда у пользователя закэшировалась более старая версия, чем вам требуется (на JQuery CDN наблюдается второе).

Comment: Значит, если я подключаю их как
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`, то этот параметр я не укажу, т.к. это устанавливает отправляющая сторона

Comment: Именно так. Если подключаете jquery с внешнего ресурса, то лучше брать CDN от гугла, он используется практически везде и работает безотказно. В итоге, у Вас будет закэшированная подгруженная библиотека jquery нужной вам версии. Но скажу сразу: тут больше шанс попасть на закэшированную версию библиотеки, если не указывать конкретную версию (берется последняя стабильная). Обратная совместимость на уровне, поэтому проблем обычно не возникает.

Comment: Если вы подключаете как указали, то вы используете JQuery CDN. Обеспечить кеширование - уже их задача (и они его обеспечивают).

Comment: Контраргументы CDN какие-то не очень.

Comment: Мало видел случаев, когда люди прям рвались использовать новые фишки версий, которые, кстати, бывают только в мажорных апдейтах. В основном, обновления jQuery идут для правки багов, улучшения производительности и налаживания кроссбраузерности. Поэтому если выбирать между тем, чтобы использовать всегда одну старую версию или последнюю стабильную, то лучше использовать последнюю стабильную, IMHO. Нахождение её в кэше наиболее вероятно.